# is there any template for creating lab manuals?

Tags: templates

I have a to make a simple lab manual for my college , 
The front page will be same as a report,
In the second page there will be an Index page of tabular form ,
Then experiment's conducted respectively,

For each experiment there will be `AIM` , `Theory` , and then `source code` and `figures` if any ,
I tried to search for any template for this type of document but I got some physics experiments manual not in the format I specified above.

how can I make this format ,Is which `\documentclass` will be suitable for me?

Comment: Can't you use a standard `report`, with one chapter per experiment?

Comment: In which way does your lab manual differ from any article or thesis you are writing? Well, instead of fixed section headings and the readers. The best starting point (template? *No*) is indeed plain old `article` or `report`. Look at `memoir` and the `KOMA` classes if you want to have more comfort.

Comment: Why do people think there must be a template for anything?

Comment: In [CTAN](http://ctan.org), you can find a [labbok](http://ctan.org/pkg/labbook) document class and in [LaTeX Templates](http://latextemplates.com) two templates for [Laboratory Books](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/laboratory-books) and one for [Laboratory Reports](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/laboratory-reports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple template that could probably fit your needs, [University/School Laboratory Report](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/university-school-laboratory-report).
Nevertheless you could define some macros on your own, since it is not that complicated.

Do you really have to create a new class file?
Maybe you just have to set up a report or article document properly, like
in the example in the link above. Afterwards you can put the set up into your
own *.tex or *.sty file (usepackage) -- some information about that 
can be found in [clsguide – Documentation of LaTeX class and package writing](http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide).

I recommend to use the standard article class
for a lab report/manual, since I am also using this class for all of my
lab reports and it works fine.

Comment: Please use templates with care and an open eye: http://www.mychemistry.eu/2013/01/latex-templates/

Comment: Of course I took a look at the template shared above. Personally I would not use it by myself since I like to define things on my own (my macros are even more TeX orientated than LaTeX based). Just thought that this link could be useful when defining an own style.

Nevertheless thank you for your comment on this!